# SharePoint 2013 online - Site template with publishing feature

Tags: sharepoint-online

Environment : SP 2013 Online Site collection with Team site template
I have requirement to create master pages so i have to enable Publishing feature at site collection and site level.

Now I have requirement to take the template of this site and move to another site collection (let say prod site). Since publishing feature is enabled I will not get option of directly taking site template. So i will make flag true in SPD, then navigate to url /_layout/savtemplate.aspx to make the template file.

After creating empty template type site collection I will upload the template file wsp in solution gallery and activate the feature.

Question - is while i am taking template should i keep my publishing feature activated or deactivated ?

Comment: Did you get the idea from below answer?

Comment: I could get but then how do i keep my dev and prod site different in online. As we cannot directly make changes in prod site so will need a backup dev site.

Comment: Are you creating a new site in PROD with having the data from (using template) DEV?

Comment: Yes, I will have some data in it

Comment: **Unsupported** Customized permissions, running workflow instances, list item version history, workflow tasks associated with running workflows, people or group field values, taxonomy field values, publishing pages and publishing sites, My Sites, stapled features, SharePoint Add-ins, and remote event receivers.

Comment: Above things did not gets saved in a template.

Comment: Try this get the template...http://www.contentprecedesdesign.net/2015/04/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-online.html

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunatelly the answer for this question is: saving publishing
>   enabled sites as a template is not supported and it does not work. You
>   cannot use this option to create new sites. Instead you should create
>   site definitions (..\web server extensions\12\template\SiteTemplates)
>   and provision the new site based on such a site definition.
>
> Also be aware that deactivating the publishing feature and creating a
>   template of the site will not lead to a supported template! The
>   problem is that the template would still contain all the artefacts of
>   a publishing site like Pages library and various different properties.
>   Creating a template of a site which previously had the publishing
>   feature activated is unsupported in the same way as creating a
>   template from a site which has the publishing feature activated.

If you disable the publishing feature and delete all content that belongs to the Publishing feature (pages library, publishing image and publishing document library and several properties in the property bag) before saving as template you would be fine.

If you keep any content related to the publishing feature – even if it is diabled – it will be affected and unsupported.

Kindly [check here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature/)

Try this article to [save site as template](http://www.contentprecedesdesign.net/2015/04/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-online.html) with publishing feature ON without PowerShell or SP Designer.

Comment: Is above answer helps you to find the resolution?

Comment: Have you found any resolution apart from my answer? Is it working for you?